# How to remove the last part of url?

Tags: c#

I have this url: `https://uk.soccerway.com/national/italy/serie-a/20172018/regular-season/r42011/?ICID=TN_02_01_02`

I want remove `?ICID=TN_02_01_02`, of couse this string is dynamic so I can't use `.Replace()` method, any idea?

Comment: [Parse it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and return only what you need.

Comment: @fantaghiro Did you require the full URL or just the path (the part after the domain and before the query string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Uri try create (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a Uri object.

Then with that Uri object take the "Query" property which will contain the entire query string.

And use "AbsolutePath" to get the URL without the query string.

Comment: FWIW AbsolutePath only returns the PATH part of the URL and not the SCHEME and AUTHORITY.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Uri` class to parse the URL. It allows you to get only up to a specific part using the [GetLeftPart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public static string GetUriWithoutQuery(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    return uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
}
```